# Renderizar pdf react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de React Native donde necesito mostrar el contenido de un PDF que obtengo a través de una API. He intentado varias formas, incluido el uso de WebView, pero no logro que funcione correctamente. Desafortunadamente, no puedo utilizar dependencias nativas debido a las restricciones de Expo Go. ¿Alguien tiene sugerencias sobre cómo puedo lograr renderizar un PDF en mi aplicación de React Native utilizando Expo? ¿Hay alternativas o enfoques que pueda considerar para resolver este problema?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { IPV4_ADDRESS } from "../views/SiteHome";

export const NodeContent = ({ route }) => {
  const { id, ticket } = route.params;
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState("");

  const fetchContentNode = async (id, ticket) => {
    const myheaders = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + ticket,
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      `http://${IPV4_ADDRESS}:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/${id}/content`,
      myheaders
    );

    const pdfUrl = response.url;
    console.log(pdfUrl)
    return pdfUrl;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPdfUrl = async () => {
      const url = await fetchContentNode(id, ticket);
      setPdfUrl(url);
    };
    getPdfUrl();
  }, [id, ticket]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {pdfUrl ? (
        <WebView source={{ uri: pdfUrl }} />
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading PDF...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```